# Circles Marker Blinking when Clicked in Leaflet R

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I couldn't tell you when, but recently I've noticed that the AddCircles output on a leaflet map seems to be blinking quite a bit when clicked on. The transition is not smooth, which wasn't the case before. There are no errors, so its very hard to pinpoint where the issue might be. Also the first image runs on a windows machine, and the second image runs on a ubuntu/shiny-server combo machine. I wonder if this makes a difference.

The Two gif files attached explain the issue pretty well.

**What is expected : NO issue in the transition**
[image: Snippet_windows_NO_Issue]

**Issue in the transition**

[image: Snippet_Ubuntu_Issue]

As is very clear in the latter, the circle disappear for a second and reappear when the user clicks on the circle to get a pop up with some information.

The R Code used to render the leaflet map :

```r
  output$map_V <- renderLeaflet({
  if (req(input$nav) == "Interactive Visualisation") {   
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE)) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik
                      , options = providerTileOptions(
                        updateWhenZooming = FALSE,      # map won't update tiles until zoom is done
                        updateWhenIdle = TRUE   # map won't load new tiles when panning
                        )) %>%
    
      setView(lng = 80.7781, lat = 7.8731, zoom = 9)
    }
```

The R Code used to render the circles :

```r
    leafletProxy("map_V", data = plotData) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(~lon_X, ~lat_Y
                 , radius=sqrt(radius) * 30
                 # , weight = 1
                 , layerId= ~CustomerRefListID
                 , group = 'CustomerRefListID'
                 , stroke=FALSE
                 , fillOpacity=0.4
                 , fillColor=pal(colorData)) %>%
      addLegend("topleft", pal=pal, values=colorData, title="Legend",layerId="colorLegend")
```

The R code used to get the click point information

```r
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map_V") %>% 
        clearPopups()
      event <- input$map_V_shape_click  #_shape_click is the attribute, we want that of map_V, the map name given above_shape_click is how the property is made
      if (is.null(event))
        return()
  
      isolate({
         showGeoPopup (event$id, lat = event$lat,lng =  event$lng)
      })
      
      # print(event$id)
    })
```

As one can clearly note, there is an issue in the lag and blinking, I was hoping to get some clarity as to where the issue might be and if so, for someone to fix the backend of it OR for some guidance regarding how to fix this problem

Thanks
piyuw

Comment: Try `req(event <- input$map_V_shape_click)` or change `observe` to `observeEvent` for the click point information.

Comment: @YBS I tried them both individually, as well as together. Unfortunately, none of them worked. What I find weird is that it doesn't happen on my windows machine, nor does it happen on shinyapps.io, however, happens on the ubuntu platform. However, it can't be the type of machine as well, because there is another observe click event on another map, but instead of circles, its the little cloud popup and it does NOT blink like the circles.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu platform. My guess was that momentarily `event` was null and therefore, the statement `if (is.null(event)) return()` would have returned `NULL` for a fraction of a second resulting in circles disappearing for a fraction of a second. If that was the case, `req()` should have fixed it. Perhaps you should try `isolate()`.

Comment: @YBS when you say use isolate(), I've already used it in the code. Where else do you suggest me using it ? for example, if you dont mind, would you be able to specify exactly where you suggest me using isolate() ?

Comment: I am not sure this will help:  `event <- isolate(input$map_V_shape_click)`, as I cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: @YBS I tried that as well, but it still doesn't solve it. Moreover, it also doesn't allow for the pop up to display. On top of that the blinking still occurs. Thanks for trying mate! much appreciate it :)